# removing bootstrap.js and jquery dependencies with main-bower-files and angular bootstrap ui

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, gulp, bower

Bower and main-bower-files are fantastic, however, when using them with Angular Bootstrap UI, more things are installed/included than required.

Basically : Angular Bootstrap UI, replaces the need for bootstrap.js and it's jquery dependency. However  when installing bootstrap, jquery gets installed, then my gulp task which uses main-bower-files, includes jquery and bootstrap.js in my html files.

Is there a way to tell bower, and/or main-bower-files and/or Bootstrap, that jquery and bootstrap.js are not required anymore.

So far I tried commenting the jquery dependency and dist/js/bootstrap.js lines in bower_components/bootstrap/bower.json, but the files are still being included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) Switch to [wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep)**, which I'd recommend. Then you can do something like this:

```
gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
  var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
  gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(wiredep({
      directory: 'app/bower_components',
      exclude: ['bootstrap']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
});
```

Note that the above will remove the whole bootstrap, not just its .js files. The `exclude` array can contain also regexps, which is what is probably needed if you want to retain for instance styles.

And in your HTML file (for javascript):

Replace the `js` with `css` where you want to inject styles.

**2) Override the bower main files for Bootstrap**: provide the following options to main-bower-files:

```
{
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        // files you want to include
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You'll have to check what you don't want to exclude  and add them to the `main` array above.

See also: https://github.com/ck86/gulp-bower-files/issues/33

Comment: You second answer does the job with main-bower-files. 

However, why do you recommend wiredep over main-bower-files+gulp-inject ?

Comment: It has worked for me and includes that 'exclude' option, so it seems to be more powerful.

Comment: Note: wiredep is abandoned.